# Can not target class after addClass

Tags: jquery, html

I have an icon that when clicked adds a class to the **nav-btn** class and the menu animates to the full height of screen.

```
$('.nav-btn').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('nav').animate({height: '100vh'});    
    });
```

When I try and close the menu by calling both the original and added class, it is unresponsive.

```
$('.nav-btn.open').click(function(){
        console.log('test');
        $('nav').animate({height: '60px'});
    });
```

I can't even see the console.log in the console so I'm thinking that I'm not calling the class correctly but I have tried a few combinations and nothing works and from reading other peoples issues I'm calling the call correctly. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are binding the click event to the `.nav-btn.open` **at runtime**, which does not exist yet (the class is only added when the user clicks the button). Instead of binding two separate events, you can combine the logic into your first click handler, and simply add a conditional check if the class `open` is present on the button:

```js
$('.nav-btn').click(function(){
  var $t = $(this);
  var $n = $('nav');

  if (!$t.hasClass('open'))
    $n.animate({height: '100vh'});
  else
    $n.animate({height: '60px'});    

  $t.toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="nav-btn">Nav Button</button>
<nav>Navigation</nav>
```

Even better: you can give store the target `height` value in a variable and use ternary operators to assign the desired value:

```js
$('.nav-btn').click(function() {
  var $t = $(this);
  var targetHeight = $t.hasClass('open') ? '60px' : '100vh';

  $('nav').animate({ height: targetHeight });
  $t.toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="nav-btn">Nav Button</button>
<nav>Navigation</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Terry, that almost works perfectly but the first instance of the click nothing happens. It works perfectly after the first click but not the very first time it is clicked. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wait it works now. I just changed the order of the animations. Thanks again, you have been a massive help.

Comment: @paulblackmore My bad, I have accidentally swapped the values around. Check the updated demo, it should work now :)

Answer (score 0):

@[Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395910/terry)'s response works just fine as well, but something else you can keep in mind is a concept called [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). As Terry explained, the problem you are experiencing is being caused because you are attaching an event handler to an element that doesn't yet exist.

However, with Event Delegation, you can attach the event to a parent element that you know will always be there (either the document, or just some container element). Using `$.on(...)`, you attach the handler to the parent element, and the event **bubbles down** to the specified element, regardless of whether it exists in the DOM yet or not.

Below, I modified your sample to show how event delegation works. (I think Terry's response is cleaner, but delegation is a helpful subject to understand).

```js
$("#btn-parent")
  .on("click", ".nav-btn.close", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open').toggleClass("close");
    $('nav').animate({height: '100vh'});
  })
  .on("click", ".nav-btn.open", function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open').toggleClass("close");
    $('nav').animate({height: '20px'});
  });
```

```css
nav {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="btn-parent">
  <button class="nav-btn close">Nav Button</button>
</div>

<nav>Navigation</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution - If the goal is only the open/close animation, the same result can be achieved with a CSS transition. This way you will only have to worry about toggling the `.open` class on and off.

```js
$('.nav-btn').on('click', function(){
   $('nav').toggleClass('open');   
});
```

```css
nav {
  border:.1em solid blue;
  height:1em;
  transition:height 300ms;
}

nav.open {
  height:80vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-btn" href="#">Navigation</a>
<nav></nav>
```